# Wrong background color

Tags: colorscheme

I installed the [iceberg](https://cocopon.github.io/iceberg.vim/) colorscheme in Vim.
It doesn't show the correct background color when running vim on *urxvt* terminals.

I tried with different terminals. Here is a result of what I got.
Top left terminal is *xterm* with a vim instance running.
Top right is *urxvt* with the another instance of vim running.
Bottom left is an empty *xterm* and bottom right an empty *urxvt*.

[image]

All those terminal have the same background color, except for urxvt with Vim which has a grey background. It should be dark-blue as the other terminals shown in the screenshot.

I checked on [colorswat.ch](http://colorswat.ch/vim/schemes/iceberg) to see which one of my Vim instances had the correct colors for this Iceberg colorscheme. It appears that the urxvt one is correct, but the background color is not.

I don't understand anything, and don't know what to search for.
I don't understand where this new background color came from.
I tried a fresh new installation of Vim with only this colorscheme and nothing more, the problem was the same.

### Edit

The *xterm* *$TERM* env variable is *xterm*. For *urxvt* it is *rxvt-unicode-256color*. On both of them, the value of *vim* *t_Co* is *256*.

I tried to set *termguicolors* as suggested in the comments. The result is not really promising:
[image]

Comment: have you tried `:set termguicolors` ?

Comment: What does Vim tell you for `:set t_Co?` on xterm and on urxvt? (I'm betting you'll get 256 on the xterm, but 16 on the urxvt.) What is `$TERM` set to on both of them? (Please [edit] your question to answer these follow ups.)